# AngularJS - $compile and nested directives inside a repeater flickering

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an array of objects which represents the state of items. Based on the type property of these objects, I need to display a different directive.

Below is a simplified version showing what I am trying (which one state directive). I have a 'renderer' directive that $compiles the needed directive based on the type property.

**Problem**: When the page loads, the nested directives show up after the compiled directives. Meaning there is a 'flicker'. This does not happen if I were to not use $compile and go for an ng-switch in the repeater.

Can anyone explain what is going on? Thank-you

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <renderer data="item"></renderer>
</div>



app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.items = [
    {
        type : 'normal',
        desc : {
            name : 'john doe',
            address : 'test',
            fax : 'test',
            phone : 'test'
        },
        desc2 : {
            name : 'another name',
            address : 'test',
            fax : 'test',
            phone : 'test'  
        }
    }
  ]
});

app.directive('renderer', function ($compile) {
return {
    restrict : 'E',
    scope : {
        data : '='
    },
    link : function (scope, element, attributes) {
        var template = '<'+ scope.data.type + ' data="data"></' + scope.data.type + '>';
        var content = $compile(template)(scope);
        element.replaceWith(content);
    }
};
});


app.directive('normal', function () {
return {
    template : '<div>Some layout content <another-directive data=ctrl.data.desc></another-directive></div>',
    controllerAs : 'ctrl',
    bindToController : {
        data : '=',
    },
    scope : {},
    controller : function () {
      //controller logic

    }
}
});
```

**UPDATE**: Updating to show the code using an ng-switch which does not flicker and displays everything at once... I would think that I would have performance issues with ng-switch inside ng-repeat rather than the renderer directive route...

```
        <div ng-repeat="item in items">
          <div ng-switch="item.type">
              <normal ng-switch-when="normal" data="item"></normal>
              <error ng-switch-when="error" data="item"></error>
              <warning ng-switch-when="warning" data="item"></warning>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: So you're saying the `Some layout content` bit renders slightly before the `another-directive`?  What happens when you try your `renderer` directive outside the `ng-repeat`?  `<renderer date="items[0]"></renderer>`  just to test

Comment: Thanks for reply plong0, it is actually the reverse, the parent divs show up slightly before nested directive and items flickers because the children's height is not defined by its content (data). That happens about 1/2 a second after...

Comment: Would it work to set a CSS `min-height` ?

Comment: Yes, I did try that and it does limit the flickering, but it is still noticeable as the nested directives render and display data. The ng-switch renders seamlessly, so still wondering why using the rendering directive not as efficient...